# Debugging javascript: breakpoint when the URL silently changes ( single page website )

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints

I m debugging a single page website , and when i go to `website.com/path` the url in nav bar changes silently to `website.com/otherpath` ( without any HTTP request being made up on that change ) , i checked the JS file and i found that the whole website is controlled from there and the webpage HTML contains only a body tag and script tags to include external scripts, and the whole DOM was appended via JS.
my question is how do i set a breakpoint in JS debugger ( chrome or mozilla ) when that path changes knowing that no HTTP requests while the DOM and the url has changed .
Thank you.

Comment: i think you are seeing some node based server package or react or something. check if you have a file called package.json. put that here. we should be able to tell you what is going on with your website.

Comment: @jay , sadly i don't have access to anything of that , i m on a black box pentest and as i said the website is single page website and when i go ```/privatepath``` the JS changes the DOM and the url bar to ```/usualpath```, knowing that both ```/privatepath``` and ```/usaulpath``` content is included in the JS file but it is too manified and too long ( 22k lines ) , i already read some of it and got a clear view of the website but i can't find the function that changes the URL .

Comment: if you just have the deployment package, what you are doing is going to get extremely complicated. I could be wrong, but if you dont have source code, but, that is not debugging that you are doing. you are essentially working backwards from the final website code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting Event listener breakpoints for `Load` in the debugger, but without knowing how the code is exactly, hard to say.